# Linear Systems, unique solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

The linear system $x-y=3$, $2x-2y=k$ cannot have a unique solution, regardless of the value of $k$.

Why is this true?

Comment: Hint: It is essentially $x-y = 3$ and $x-y = k/2$.

Comment: Oh.  If k is not 6 then the system is inconsistent.  If k is 6 then there still isn't a unique solution because the second equation provides no new information...

Answer (score 1):

Well, rewrite your first equation as $x=y+3.$ Substitution into the second equation yields $6=k$. If $k=6,$ then *every* pair $(x,y)$ with $x=y+3$ is a solution, and if not, then *no* pair $(x,y)$ is a solution.

Put another way: lines in the plane with the same slope are either non-intersecting, or are in fact the same line. They cannot intersect at a single point only.

Answer (score 0):

Pick some different values of $k$ and graph the lines. What do they look like? Now see what about the two equations (*cough* slopes *cough*) reflects what the lines are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc} 2 & -2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} k \\ 3 \end{array}\right]
$$
The square matrix on  the left has a determinant of $0$, so it is singular, and no inverse exists. If you haven't gotten there yet, try using Cramer's rule and see what you get.